# How do configure Apache to resolve 'Missing Cross-Frame Scripting Defence' by app scan

Tags: php, appsec, apache, cross-frame-scripting

There is an apache server hosting some website written in PHP and is accessible thru internet. How do configure the apache to resolve 'Missing Cross-Frame Scripting Defence' and can 'Missing Cross-Frame Scripting Defence' warning be ignored?

Comment: Same note as your previous question: I think this is better to ask in SuperUser website.

Comment: I think that this question is better suitable for ServerFault than SuperUser.

Comment: dear moderators, please enlighten me if I should ask in SuperUser or ServerFault. thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest SuperUser - see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send an [X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options), usually with the value "sameorigin". You can do this in Apache using [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html), something like:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options sameorigin
```